# Changing the tolerance of findAt() function

Tags: python, abaqus

I am using the `findAt()` function in `Abaqus` but quite often it doesn't find the element, even thought the reference location is quite close. This is because the tolerance it uses to find objects is `1e-6` on default.

(https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAECMDRefMap/simacmd-c-intaclregions.htm)

I would like to relax/change this tolerance. Does anybody know if this is possible?

```
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['x'].Set(faces=/mdb.models['Model1'].parts['x'].faces.findAt(.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find faces by larger tolerance you should use `getByBoundingBox`. There you can specify the range with your tolerance. e.g.

```
point = (x,y,z) # your coordinates
tol = 1e-5 # your tolerance
faces = mdb.models['Model1'].parts['x'].faces.getByBoundingBox(xMin = point[0]-tol, xMax = point[0]+tol,yMin = point[1]-tol, yMax = point[1]+tol,zMin = point[2]-tol, zMax = point[2]+tol,) # faces on the coordinates within your tolerance
```

Further you could advance this by making a function so you can apply the same procedure on list of coordinates as in `findAt` method.

EDIT:

Or even better `getByBoundingSphere`. In this case it's even easier:

```
point = (x,y,z) # your coordinates
tol = 1e-5 # your tolerance
faces = mdb.models['Model1'].parts['x'].faces.getByBoundingSphere(center = point, radius=tol) # faces on the coordinates within your tolerance
```

EDIT2:
Forget the above. use `getClosest`. there you can specify list of coordinates and a tolerance so behavior is like a `findAt` just with custom tolerance.

```
point = (x,y,z) # your coordinates
point2 = (x2,y2,z2) # your coordinates
tol = 1e-5 # your tolerance
faces = mdb.models['Model1'].parts['x'].faces.getClosest(coordinates =(point,point2), searchTolerance=tol) # faces on the coordinates within your tolerance
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, few notes for others using it:
1. The bounding box requires the full face to be inside it, making it really hard to assign all geometry without accidentally assigning some twice
2. The getClosest doesn't seem to be working with faces, it is meant to create edge group https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Abaqus610/Documentation/docs/v6.10/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch06pyo04.html#ker-edgearray-getclosest-pyc
3. I ended up using the sphere method, although it also has the enclosure issue (as per point 1 made) my faces have quite standard sizes, so it works

Comment: @LuTze, While you are right about the box and sphere that the face has to be contained in it. getClosest realy does work as one should expect. You linked a wrong place in the manual. Look [here](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Abaqus610/Documentation/docs/v6.10/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch06pyo06.html#ker-facearray-getclosest-pyc)